# Endless data loop from dev/ttyUSB while sending AT commands

Tags: linux, terminal, serial-port, usb, modem

I have problem sending AT commands to my USB modem.
At first I tried php-serial class, but when i was reading data, I got endless loop with strange data. Then I tried to debug problem and opened putty terminal, made command

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and then sent command `echo "AT" > /dev/ttyUSB0` after that I always got never ending loop from cat /dev/ttyUSB0 like this:

```
AT
AT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^JAT^
```

and this loop never ends. On windows all works just fine. I can connect to USB modem via virtual COM port and send command / get answer.

Question is why cant I just receive "OK" message from console, but instead of this I got this data loop ?

Tried different huawei USB modems, and different stty settings and also default settings for huawei modems:

```
Baud rate: 9600 / 115200
Parity: none
Data bits = 8
Stop bits = 1
Flow control = none
```

Comment: This looks like a Linux-specific problem with little to do with programming, and as such I would recommend that it be migrated to the [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree that this is not programming related, and think this question belongs here.